# How to completely save large chat history of WhatsApp in Android phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, export

To save a large (group) chat history of WhatsApp on an Android phone, I have looked to the internet for help - but still cannot save/backup the entire conversation/chat from the beginning.

For information, my example is a group chat with history composed of maybe a few hundred text messages (starting in 2017), containing maybe thirty images, a few videos, and some short voice files. It definitely should not exceed the limits of the WhatsApp system. There is nothing rude in the chat but some strong feelings are expressed by some, in any case, should not fall foul with any censorship.

I can see the entire chat (from beginning to current) on my phone, but when I export the chat via email and Gmail it only shows approx. one month of chat.

I use the procedure advised by the internet including this forum that I am writing in. I use the selections: More, Export Chat, Include Media, Send chat via (and each time click Email or Gmail), type into the To field, then send. It sends but in checking the sent mail, can only see recent chats.

So why can I not backup the entire chat history? What is limiting and preventing seeing (exporting?) the entire chat history?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whatsapp: Export chat with media does not work properly](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223947/whatsapp-export-chat-with-media-does-not-work-properly)

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit which is imposed because of the maximum sizes of emails.

See [the WhatsApp FAQ section](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/23756533/) of their website

> If you choose to attach media, the most recent media sent will be added as attachments. When sending with media, you can send up to 10,000 latest messages. Without media, you can send 40,000 messages. These constraints are due to maximum email sizes.

Comment: there is nothing specifically different in having to save chats in groups differently.
Suspect this would be worth raising a support ticket with WhatsApp

Comment: justamarkprime, thanks for quick reply. I knew WhatsApp had the limits (with / without media), however, our group chat history is only composed of maybe a few hundred text messages (quite short and starting in 2017), it also contains maybe thirty images, a few videos and some short voice files. That size of history should not exceed the WhatsApp limits mentioned. It would be very surprising if it did. If it did exceed limit, why when I export via Email/Gmail it can only backup about one month worth of chat which is about 30 messages???

Comment: Surely something else must be causing the limit/restriction? If these constraints are due to maximum email sizes, how do I backup the chats that are over a month ago all the way to 2017 when the group chat began?