# Importing messages from Whatsapp to Telegram has size and count limitation

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, telegram, export

Telegram has [recently announced](https://telegram.org/blog/move-history) that you can transfer chat history from Whatsapp and some other apps to Telegram. I tried to export a chat from one of my contacts in Whatsapp but I realized that it has not been exported completely.

On [Whatsapp website](https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/how-to-save-your-chat-history/?lang=en), it says there is 10,000 messages limitation if you include media and a 40,000 messages limitation if you don't include media.

But actually after some research I found [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223971) that says there is also a size limitation (how many megabytes) which can limit the number of messages to be exported way below 10,000 if you include media because you might have many images or voices.

Is there a workaround that I can export all the messages in a Whatsapp chat to Telegram?

For example a possible workaround might be that first I export to Telegram then come to Telegram and see what has been exported. After that, I go to Whatsapp and delete the previous exported messages and do this process for the remaining messages until no messages remains in Whatsapp. But I have not tried such a workaround.